# How to get angle using camera?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

NOTE: i have only user height h
And i need to get angle AA'B so i can use these value to get distance of object.

i need to calculate distance of object from camera for which in need to  calculate angle AA'B
Check below pic

Is i need gyroscope of something to calculate it?

[image]

How i caluate it?

i can calculate Field of view using

```
float FOV = camera.activeFormat.videoFieldOfView;
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry

Comment: You can use the accelerometer to do so...

Comment: if you want just the angle, have you tried gyroscope? or do need to support older devices without gyroscope?

Comment: i used gyroscope but how i know that angle is at the bottom point? And its changes so frequently...is it the right calculation of angle?